Is this correct to run a CPU-bound operation using ProcessPoolExecutor in asyncio loop?
I'm trying to run CPU-bound operations in non-blocking style using ProcessPoolExecutor from concurrent.futures module and asyncio.get_running_loop() functions.
I have my function that runs CPU-bound operations with polars under the hood. Second function runs first function in a ProcessPool using asyncio loop. Will this result in a bad performance or functions implemented like this one will run in separate processes and everything is fine?
def process_zip_file(file: ZipFile):
    try:
        csv_files = unzip_file(file) 
    except Exception as e:
        raise ZipfileProcessingError("Error unzipping file.")

    try:
        dataframes = create_dataframes(csv_files) # polars operations under the hood

        concat_df = concat_dataframes(dataframes, file.filename)
        return concat_df
    except Exception as e:
        module_logging.error(e)
        raise DataframeProcessingErorr("Error processing csv files.")



async def process_zip_file_concurrent(zip_file: ZipFile):
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as excecutor:
        result = await loop.run_in_executor(excecutor, process_zip_file, zip_file)    
    return result


my only concern is that you should be reusing this pool instead of creating it every time. otherwise it is hard to judge which is faster without benchmarking it, it really depends on how much work is being done inside create_dataframes

both disk IO and socket IO from returning things from the other process don't happen while the GIL is held, so this has a good chance of giving you better performance, but the unpickling happens while the GIL is held, so it is not exactly zero cost, but it is really platform dependent, for example importing pandas and polars into a new process could take like 6 seconds, so this will be much slower on windows and macOS, especially since you are not reusing the workers
